# Pycharm does not show recommendations

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a class called myDevice and it looks like this:

```
from FeaturesetAlpha import FeaturesetAlphaWrapper

class MyDeviceWrapper:
    def __init__(self, cs_object):
        self.cs_object = cs_object
        self.alpha = FeaturesetAlphaWrapper(cs_object.alpha)
```

When I create a new devicewrapper and try deviceWrapper. It does not show `alpha.` when I say `deviceWrapper.alpha` it works, but do you know why it does not show recommendations? I am using python.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what `FeaturesetAlphaWrapper` is.

Comment: It is working fine, it just does not show me the recommendation

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (including fixing the various typos involving the class name `MyDeviceWrapper`).

Comment: Yes – sounds like PyCharm can't infer what to do with `FeaturesetAlphaWrapper`.

Comment: Same code does show the recommendations with my colleague. The problem is with my pycharm settings

Comment: Well, great – then you can compare your PyCharm settings with your colleague's and figure out what's wrong.

Comment: For [autocomplete to work in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpycharm%5D+autocomplete&searchOn=3) you need a number of things depending on your environment. You're not giving us enough information to diagnose the problem other than "it works for my colleagues". Check the linked threads they should contain everything you need to get it working.